# How to set URL when getting URL from another activity?

Tags: android, json

I am sending my URL from one activity to another like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class).putExtra("key", fullurl));
```

And getting it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
}
```

How to put it in here?

```
jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txt.setText(url);

    new DownloadJSON().execute();
}

private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        world = new ArrayList<>();

        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);
        try {
            // Some code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see the correct url inside the textview after getting it from the Bundle?

Comment: yes, the correct URL is shown in the text view.

Comment: are you getting any error or crash?... you code looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

// Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

```
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                    String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                    String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                    String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your url is a string and that you want to convert it to an URL object.

```
    URL mUrl = new URL(url);
    URI uri = new URI(mUrl.getProtocol(), mUrl.getUserInfo(), mUrl.getHost(), mUrl.getPort(), mUrl.getPath(), mUrl.getQuery(), mUrl.getRef());
    mUrl = uri.toURL();
```

After this u can use JSONfunctions .getJSONfromURL(mUrl);

Comment: Getting exception URl syntax exception

Comment: String url = "www.abc.com/funlearn/chapterDetails?topicId=";

                String fullurl = url + newid + "&page=" + topic;

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Change

```
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
```

to

```
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground((URL... url) {
```

**Step 2**

Change

```
new DownloadJSON().execute();
```

to

```
try{
    URL myUrl = new URL(url);
    new DownloadJSON().execute(myUrl);
}
catch(MalformedURLException mue){
    Log.e("Invalid url","Invalid url");
}
```

**Step 3**

Change

```
jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);
```

to

```
jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url[0]);
```

Comment: unhandled exception on this line new DownloadJSON().execute(new URL(url));  Malformed url exception

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh Updated step 2

Comment: jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url[0]);  in this line arraytype expected found java.lang.String

Comment: this method must be accepting array. Don't use **step 3** then

Comment: Please post method `getJSONfromURL` for better help. Looks like you don't even need to convert url string to `URL`